# React - how to pass the correct prop to a child component from a long running operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nonblocking

I have a simple react class...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProbabilityGraph from './GraphComponent/ProbabilityGraph'
import * as d3dsv from "d3-dsv";
import * as d3request from "d3-request";     
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    const url = 'http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/someCSV.csv';

    const dataReq = d3request.request(url).get(function(error, data){
        // console.log(data);
        const dataFinal = d3dsv.csvParse( data.responseText)
        return dataFinal    
            // console.log(dataFinal)
    });


    return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <h1> Maybe Do Something </h1>

        <ProbabilityGraph data={dataReq}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The d3request and parse takes a bit of time. What I think is happening, is that the dataFinal variable hasn't been filled up by the time react initialies the component, so nothing gets rendered.

What's the corect answer to this? The 'ProbabilityGraph' will process the data a little further and then renders a line (it's based on Victory Charts)... works nicely with some sample data.

Comment: After received data it renders correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `state` after long operation with the help of  `this.setState` as soon as you will call this method it will force the component to render again but now your state will have some value which you can access with `this.state.XXX` and pass this to your children,

It is prefered to do these sort of operations inside the `componentDidMount()` so that it shouldn't block the render of the component.

Change your code to below will work for you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProbabilityGraph from './GraphComponent/ProbabilityGraph'
import * as d3dsv from "d3-dsv";
import * as d3request from "d3-request";     
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state = {
            dataReq: {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const url = 'http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/someCSV.csv';

        d3request.request(url).get(function(error, data){
            const dataFinal = d3dsv.csvParse( data.responseText)
            this.setState({dataReq: dataFinal});

        });
    }
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <h1> Maybe Do Something </h1>

        { dataReq && <ProbabilityGraph data={this.state.dataReq}/> }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "dataReq" state. Then in the componentDidMount() cycle fetch your data, and update your "dataReq" state. This will trigger a re-render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProbabilityGraph from './GraphComponent/ProbabilityGraph'
import * as d3dsv from "d3-dsv";
import * as d3request from "d3-request";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataReq = {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/someCSV.csv';

    d3request.request(url).get(function(error, data){
      const dataFinal = d3dsv.csvParse( data.responseText)

      this.setState({dataReq: dataFinal})
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <h1> Maybe Do Something </h1>
        <ProbabilityGraph data={this.state.dataReq}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```